# *Not browse images* WYSIWYG editor not showing images properly

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image, backend, wysiwyg

This is my first time posting here, but I am having a problem that not a lot of people seem to be having, I have only found one image of my problem on google.

So, after updating from magento 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.2, WYSIWYG is not showing images properly in backend.

[image: 1]

Note: I have replaced my website name and admin URL with "xxxxx".

[image: 1]

Also images inserted from other websites such as imgur . com work fine, only the ones from my website are broken.

P.S: I am also having issues with the flash uploader being removed, but I have fixed that by using a HTML 5 uploader, so that should be unrelated to this issue.

P.S 2: The images only appear broken in the editor, they are properly displayed on the frontend.

Firefox console shows this:

[image: 2]